# How to import databricks operators into airflow container?

Tags: import, dependencies, airflow, databricks

I am trying to run an simple dag with only a dummy- and a databricksoperator (DatabricksRunNowOperator) just to test it. I uploaded the dag into the airflow container, but the databricks operator is not part of the ordinary airflow package. I installed it (locally) with pip install apache-airflow-providers-databricks. Accordingly, the package is not present in the container and an error occurs.

Does anyone know how I provide the mentioned package to the airflow container?

Answer (score 0):

if you use docker compose as recommended by the official [Airflow documentation on Docker setup](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml), then you can specify additional dependencies with `_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS` environment variable (also could be put into `.env` file in the same folder). For example, I have following in my testing environment:

```
_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS="apache-airflow-providers-databricks==2.4.0rc1"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for - now it works.